# Getting error while trying to do image inpainting using wavelet Transform

Tags: image, wavelet, inpainting

This is my code :

```
from google.colab import files
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt

def wavelet_inpainting(image, mask, wavelet='haar', level=3, threshold=20):
    # Apply discrete wavelet transform
    coeffs = pywt.wavedec2(image, wavelet, level=level)

    # Thresholding
    for i in range(1, len(coeffs)):
        coeffs[i] = pywt.threshold(coeffs[i], threshold, mode='soft')

    # Resize the mask to match the size of the detailed coefficients
    mask_resized = cv2.resize(mask, (coeffs[1][1].shape[1], coeffs[1][1].shape[0]))

    # Inpainting by replacing coefficients in masked regions with zeros
    for i in range(1, len(coeffs)):
        coeffs[i] *= np.logical_not(mask_resized)

    # Reconstruct the image
    reconstructed_image = pywt.waverec2(coeffs, wavelet)

    return reconstructed_image


uploaded_scratched = files.upload()
uploaded_mask = files.upload()

# Get the uploaded file names
scratched_file = list(uploaded_scratched.keys())[0]
mask_file = list(uploaded_mask.keys())[0]

# Load the image and mask
img = cv2.imread(scratched_file)
mask = cv2.imread(mask_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Print image sizes for debugging
print("Image size:", img.shape)
print("Mask size:", mask.shape)

# Apply wavelet inpainting
inpainted_image = wavelet_inpainting(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), mask, wavelet='db4', level=3, threshold=20)

# Display the images using matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Image with missing pixels')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Mask of the missing pixels')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(inpainted_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Image with missing pixels inpainted (Wavelet)')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

### when I run the code i am getting this error :
426635114_913424343857746_8690554790498755996_n.jpg
426635114_913424343857746_8690554790498755996_n.jpg(image/jpeg) - 54031 bytes, last modified: 19/02/2024 - 100% done
Saving 426635114_913424343857746_8690554790498755996_n.jpg to 426635114_913424343857746_8690554790498755996_n (5).jpg
416571261_389155413710070_7408430380404039926_n.jpg
416571261_389155413710070_7408430380404039926_n.jpg(image/jpeg) - 33633 bytes, last modified: 19/02/2024 - 100% done
Saving 416571261_389155413710070_7408430380404039926_n.jpg to 416571261_389155413710070_7408430380404039926_n (4).jpg
Image size: (1080, 1623, 3)
Mask size: (1080, 1623)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 44>()
42
43 # Apply wavelet inpainting
---> 44 inpainted_image = wavelet_inpainting(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), mask, wavelet='db4', level=3, threshold=20)
45
46 # Display the images using matplotlib

in wavelet_inpainting(image, mask, wavelet, level, threshold)
18     # Inpainting by replacing coefficients in masked regions with zeros
19     for i in range(1, len(coeffs)):
---> 20         coeffs[i] *= np.logical_not(mask_resized)
21
22     # Reconstruct the image

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,275,411) (141,209) (3,275,411)

I was trying to do image inpainting by using wavelet transform. But I was getting the error and could not run the code properly.